# Ordered Sets (Bernd Schröder)

Tags: order-theory, lattice-orders

Considered the power set $\mathcal{P}(\{ 1,...,n \})$ with the following relation. The set $A$ is said to be **dominated** by the set $B$ iff there is a $k$ such that $|\{ 1,...,k \} \cap A| < |\{ 1,...,k \} \cap B|$ and, for all $l<k$, we have $|\{ 1,...,l \} \cap A| = |\{ 1,...,l \} \cap B|$. Define $A \leq B$ iff $A = B$ or $A$ is dominated by $B$.

How do I prove that it is an ordered set?

Somebody help me please.

Comment: When a set $S$ (such as $\{1,...,n\}$) is endowed with a well-order $<_W$ (such as the arithmetic order on $\{1,...,n\}$) and $F$ is a set of some or all of the subsets of $S$,  the lexicographic (or dictionary) order $\le$ on $F$ is defined as follows: if $A,B\in F$ with $A\ne B$ let $d(A,B)$ be the $<_W$-least member of $A\Delta B=(A\setminus B)\cup (B\setminus A)$. Then  let $A\le B$ iff $d(A,B)\in B.$

Answer (score 2):

Notice that, if 
$$|\{1,\ldots,k\} \cap A| < |\{1,\ldots,k\} \cap B|,$$
while
$$|\{1,\ldots,l\} \cap A| = |\{1,\ldots,l\} \cap B|,$$
for $l<k$, then $k \in B \setminus A$.

Let us now prove that the relation is reflexive, anti-symmetric, and transitive.
Reflexivity is trivial, since $A=A$ for every subset $A$ of $\{ 1,\ldots,n \}$.

For anti-symmetry, suppose $A \leq B$ and $B \leq A$.
I'll leave the trivial case in which $A=B$, and show that if $A< B$ and $B < A$ then we get a contradiction.
So suppose that 
$$|\{1,\ldots,k_1\} \cap A| < |\{1,\ldots,k_1\} \cap B|,$$
while
$$|\{1,\ldots,l\} \cap A| = |\{1,\ldots,l\} \cap B|,$$
for $l < k_1$, and that
$$|\{1,\ldots,k_2\} \cap B| < |\{1,\ldots,k_2\} \cap A|,$$
while
$$|\{1,\ldots,l\} \cap A| = |\{1,\ldots,l\} \cap B|,$$
for $l < k_2$.
If $k_1 < k_2$ then, in particular,
$$|\{1,\ldots,k_1\} \cap A| = |\{1,\ldots,k_1\} \cap B|,$$
a contradiction.
A similar contradiction is obtained if we suppose that $k_1 > k_2$, and if $k_1=k_2$, then the contradiction follows from $k_1 \in B\setminus A$ and $k_2 \in A \setminus B$.
Hence $A=B$.

For transitivity, suppose $A \leq B \leq C$.
Leaving out the immediate cases where $A=B$ or $B=C$, we get $A<B<C$, and for some $k_1,k_2$,
$$|\{1,\ldots,k_1\} \cap A| < |\{1,\ldots,k_1\} \cap B|,$$
while
$$|\{1,\ldots,l\} \cap A| = |\{1,\ldots,l\} \cap B|,$$
for $l < k_1$, and 
$$|\{1,\ldots,k_2\} \cap B| < |\{1,\ldots,k_2\} \cap C|,$$
while
$$|\{1,\ldots,l\} \cap B| = |\{1,\ldots,l\} \cap C|,$$
for $l < k_2$. 
Since $k_1 \in B$ and $k_2 \in C\setminus B$, we get $k_1 \neq k_2$.
If $k_1 < k_2$, then for $l < k_1$,
$$|\{1,\ldots,l\} \cap A| = |\{1,\ldots,l\} \cap B| = |\{1,\ldots,l\} \cap C|,$$
while
$$|\{1,\ldots,k_1\} \cap A| < |\{1,\ldots,k_1\} \cap B| = |\{1,\ldots,k_1\} \cap C|.$$
If $k_2 < k_1$, then for $l < k_2$,
$$|\{1,\ldots,l\} \cap A| = |\{1,\ldots,l\} \cap B| = |\{1,\ldots,l\} \cap C|,$$
while
$$|\{1,\ldots,k_2\} \cap A| = |\{1,\ldots,k_2\} \cap B| < |\{1,\ldots,k_1\} \cap C|.$$
Therefore $A \leq C$.